# How to Call Javascript function in ASPxPopupControl_WindowCallback in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an ASPxPopupControl and in Callback Function I want to call a javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowAlert() {
      alert('Display Message Alert');
    }   
</script>


protected void ASPxPopupControl_WindowCallback(object source, DevExpress.Web.ASPxPopupControl.PopupWindowCallbackArgs e) {

    I want to Call ShowAlert() javascript function from here
}

I tried this code but it only works on button click event

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "MyKey",                 "ShowDetailView();", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working code which will invoke the javascript function from codebehind.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowAlert() {
      alert('Display Message Alert');
 }   
</script>
```

**Code Behind**

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Call my function", "ShowAlert();", true);
```

**Extra** in case if you want to open a window in javascript instead of a pop up ,

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "Alert", "window.open('description.aspx','Mywindow','scrollbars=Yes,width=800,menubar=yes, resizable=No');", true);
```

Comment: Hi CodeBrain, the codes works fine under button click event. But i need to put it under ASPxPopup_WindowCallback the code does not execute. Is there a way or a work around for this? Thanks!

Comment: The complete flow of this goes like this, I have an ASPxPivotGrid Control that performs ASPxPopupControl Callback on Cell Click for the purpose of getting some values for parameters. After getting the values i need to call the javascript function which displays the new page or display message. I'm stuck right now on how to call javascript from callback. Thanks